# Xcode 9.2 Interface builder not showing objects during runtime

Tags: ios, xcode

Out of the blue today, I wanted to add a UIButton via Interface builder, but I noticed the button doesn't appear on the screen when I run the app?!
I have multiple views, and on all of them adding an object (button, textview etc) via IB will not show when the app is build and runned?!

I cleaned the project, removed derived data, restarted xcode, even used an backup (previous) version of the app, no joy...

Any others experiencing this issue? this is on xcode 9.2

Comment: did you debug the view hirarchy?

Comment: If you can attach a screenshot of IB after runtime.

Comment: I think it was due to the new Xcode localisation feature. I upgraded the project from an older xcode version, and it seems to create multiple storyboards for localisation. I merged it all back to one storyboard and the seemed to solve it..